# What is a good book on brochure design?

Tags: print-design, layout

I'm looking for good books about creating brochures to learn more about how to structure one and such. I've tried to search Amazon but could mostly only find more inspirational-focused books (a lot of pictures of brochures). I'm not looking for books such as grids, typography etc.

I'm looking for books on how to create content (including copy writing and art direction), disposition and planning the layout of the brochure.

Books about grids explains how to use the grid but not in which order content should be placed. Books about art direction are mostly focused on print adverting, and not longer brochures. Graphic design books care very little about the actual content, and just asumes that someone will hand it over to you. That is my experience.

Here's an online article about the subject that I'm looking for: https://designshack.net/how-to-design-a-brochure/

Comment: --- *"... only find more inspirational-focused ... I'm not looking for books such as grids, typography etc."* -- Then what **are** you looking for? I mean that's the gamut.. either inspirational or technical.

Comment: Good point. I'm looking for books on how to create content (including copy writing and art direction), and planning the layout of the brochure. I have yet found a book about those things. Books about grids explains how to use the grid but not in which order content should com. Books about art direction are mostly focused on print adverting, and not longer brochures.

Comment: Well I don't think you'll find anything. Copy writing is *writing* and there is a great deal of education or experience required to write good copy. As for planning, well that's just general design workflow. *What* a specific project may be makes little difference other than reproduction constraints. I'd hazard a guess that there's no "money" in creating a book for "How to write and plan your brochure."  Professional writers learned how to write effectively. Professional designers learned how to design effectively. The practices implemented are universal, not specific to one type of project.

Comment: In short, you'd need *general* books on writing effective copy and *general* books on designing effective marketing. Nothing is going to be overly specific to "brochures".

Comment: Thanks for your engagement with the question. I know that there are books about copywriting and marketing and graphic design in general. That's why I'm looking for a book that is specifically about broschure design. I know that the market for broschure design books is not big now, but sometime during the last 70 years or so I hoped that someone wrote a book about the topic.

Comment: Decent link, but ultimately it's click-bait and you'll find it as helpful as a web page on "How to start a business". *Yes* the content is decent and largely within the realm of reality. But there's generally considerably more real-world factors to each and every point cited there.

Comment: @TonyBolero a brochure is not sufficiently different from making a poster, booklet and magazine to warrant a separate explanation. Since the same general explanation covers all of them.

Comment: This is such a great discussion :) – I know that the linked article is not enough. That is why I’m looking for a book about broschures, not some shallow click bait article. It’ ok if it also contain info about booklets, but there is a clear difference between an attention grabbing poster and say a company presentation or a product catalogue or an exhibition folder.